# how to filter inner quotes?

Tags: awk, regular-expression, quoting, special-characters

is it possible to filter, i.e to put ESC in front of the inner quotes with **sed**, **awk** or other *NIX tool (no perl/python)?

Example (revised):

```
$ echo label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh | magic-filter
label="123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C" e f gh
```

<del>label="123 \"456\" 789" "AB C"</del>

In other words a filter is needed that will filter in the following way:
the first and last **"** char will be passed as is, but all other **"** will be replaced with **\** followed by **"**.

Comment: By which rule is it possible to define which `"` is "internal"? You could have as well selected the first and the last as external and the rest as internal. There are several other alternative selections.

Comment: That is correct remark! Let's assume all quotes between th 1st and last as inner.

Comment: @ivand58 you should [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GNU sed`, which supports [replacing all occurrences from particular count](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/15518/pattern-flags-occurrence-replacement#t=201610240526583938211)

```
$ echo label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh | 
    sed -E 's/"/\\"/2g; s/\\("[^"]*)$/\1/'
label="123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C" e f gh
```

All `"` (expect first `"`) are replaced with `\"` and then `\` is removed from last `\"`

If `GNU sed` is not available, remove `\` from first `\"` as well

```
$ echo label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh | 
    sed -E 's/"/\\"/g; s/\\"/"/; s/\\("[^"]*)$/\1/'
label="123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C" e f gh
```

Note: Some `sed` versions might need `-r` instead of `-E`

With `perl`

```
$ echo label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh | 
    perl -pe 's/(^[^"]*"|"[^"]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|"/\\"/g'
label="123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C" e f gh
```

Here, the string up to first `"` and string from last `"` to end of line are **skipped** while the remaining `"` are replaced with `\"`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` to the rescue.

```
sed 's/"/\x1b"/g;s/\x1b"/"/;s/\(.*\)\x1b"/\1"/'
```

Replace all quotes with `ESC"` and then revisit and replace first with just quote, and replace final with just quote.  Detailed explanation:

- `s/"/\x1b"/g` : replace all quote characters with \x1b (ESC) and quote.
- `s/\x1b"/"/` : replace first \x1b (ESC) and quote combination with single quote.
- `s/\(.*\)\x1b"/\1"/` : replace final \x1b (ESC) and quote combination with single quote

Example output:

```
$ echo label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh |sed 's/"/\x1b"/g;s/\x1b"/"/;s/\(.*\)\x1b"/\1"/'|od -c
0000000   l   a   b   e   l   =   "   1   2   3     033   "   4   5   6
0000020 033   "       7   8   9 033   "     033   "   A   B       C   "
0000040       e       f       g   h  \n
0000050
$
```

Comment: the problem is not in the echo, I looking for a filter. Here the echo part is given for illustration a test case

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get what you ask for in several steps:
Assuming a variable could contain the string (the string doesn't have single quotes):

```
$ label='label=\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C\" e f gh'
```

We could chop out the part after the `\"`:

```
$ front=${label%\\\"*}
$ echo "$front"
\"123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C
```

Then remove up to the first `\"`:

```
$ mid=${front#*\"}
$ echo "$mid"
123 \"456\" 789\" \"AB C
```

Replace all `\"` by `\e"`:

```
$ final=${mid//\\\"/\\e}
$ echo "$final"
123 \e456\e 789\e \eAB C
```

And finally, reconstruct the original string and use printf for the escapes:

```
$ printf "label=\"${front%%\\\"*}$final\"${label#"${front}"}\n"
label="123 456 789 AB C"" e f gh

$ printf "label=\"${front%%\\\"*}$final\"${label#"${front}"}\n" | od -vAn -t x1c
  6c  61  62  65  6c  3d  22  31  32  33  20  1b  22  34  35  36
   l   a   b   e   l   =   "   1   2   3     033   "   4   5   6
  1b  22  20  37  38  39  1b  22  20  1b  22  41  42  20  43  22
 033   "       7   8   9 033   "     033   "   A   B       C   "
  22  20  65  20  66  20  67  68  0a
   "       e       f       g   h  \n
```